# Finding optimal mixed strategy

Tags: game-theory

I have to find an optimal mixed strategy for the 'column' player, who mixes with the probabilites $q_1,q_2,q_3$. What is known is the optimal mixing of the 'row" player. The game is a zero-sum game, each entry represents Row's gain, and Column's loss.

$\begin{bmatrix} &q_1 &q_2 &q_3\\ p=\frac{4}{7}& 4&5&2\\ 1-p=\frac{3}{7}&3& 1 &5 \end{bmatrix}$

I thought I should calculate the value of the game, so I wrote:

$\frac{4}{7}(4q_1+5q_2+2q_3)+\frac{3}{7}(3q_1+1q_2+5q_3)=$

$=\frac{25}{7}q_1+\frac{23}{7}q_2+\frac{23}{7}q_3$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you supposed to find the optimal mixed strategy for Column on the assumption that Row is locked into the strategy shown? Or are you looking for a Nash equilibrium, where each player's strategy is optimal given the other's? Those are two different questions.

Comment: A related question: is this a zero-sum game, so that each entry represents Column's gain and also Row's loss? Or are Row's payoff's not shown?

Comment: I edited the question. Row's strategy is an optiaml mixed strategy. So, yes Row is locked into that.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that a strategy $p$ of the row player is part of a Nash equilibrium , you can find a strategy $q$ of the column player so that $(p,q)$ is a Nash equilibrium (even if the game is not zero-sum) as follows:

1. Find the set $Q$ of pure best responses to $p$. In this case $Q = \{2,3\}$, that is columns 2 and 3.
2. Check which mixtures over $Q$ make the pure strategies in the support of $p$ pure best responses (where the support of $p$ is those pure strategies that are played with positive probability, i.e. $\{i \mid p_i > 0\}$). In the example, the unique way to mix over columns 2 and 3 to make the row player indifferent (which is necessary and sufficient for both rows to be best responses) is to set $q = (0, 3/7, 4/7)$. This is an easy calculation that equated the expected payoff of the rows against a mixed strategy $q = (0,q_2,1-q_2)$. Since this game is zero sum and this was the unique way to make $p$ a best response, we have that $(p,q)$ is the unique Nash equilibrium of this game.

More generally, for solving $2 \times N$ bimatrix games see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/mixed-strategy-nash-equilibria-in-from-2-times-n-bimatrix-form) to another question, which describes the "upper envelope method". For zero-sum games in particular, to look for equilibrium strategies you can look for maxmin strategies, which is easy for the row player in a $2 \times N$ game using the upper envelope method.

To explore other games and check that you can solve them correctly, you might find the following web-based software useful:

http://banach.lse.ac.uk

http://www.gametheoryexplorer.org

We actively develop the second, so feedback is welcome.

Comment: has the http://www.gametheoryexplorer.com/ address moved? I used the http://banach.lse.ac.uk/ website to solve some small matrices (which was extremely helpful!) but I'm curious what is on the `game theory explorer' website.

Comment: @ryan: No, it was a typo, thanks for spotting that. http://www.gametheoryexplorer.org also allows to draw and solve extensive-form games.

Answer (score 1):

Given the question as you've clarified it, [EDITED FROM HERE ON TO CORRECT FOR MY FAILURE TO READ THE UPDATED QUESTION CAREFULLY ENOUGH], yes in response to your comment, you want to minimize Row's payoff by having Column zero out $q_1$ and pick any $q_2$ and $q_3$ that add up to 1. This is because those two have the same coefficient, 23/7, and it's less than 25/7.

Comment: No, these are row's payoffs, but the value of the game in equilibrium is the same for both row and column. So I should somehow minimize the sum I wrote? But how?

Comment: I could calculate the expected payoffs for Row: $4p_1+3p_2=\frac{25}{7}$ $5p_1+p_2=\frac{23}{7}$ and $2p_1+5p_2=\frac{23}{7}$.
Now, the $\frac{23}{7}$ equals $4q_1+5q_2+2q_3=3q_1+1q_2+5q_3$
is that right?

Comment: We know column's payoffs. Since the game is zero-sum, Column's payoffs equal to -1*row's payoffs.

Comment: Ah, sorry in your edit I overlooked where you added zero-sum. My error. In that case Column will respond to Row's current strategy by picking some indifferent mix of columns two and three to minimize Row's payoff. Look at your equation and see how that works. The one thing we know is Column will stay away from the first option.