# Game Theory Mixed Strategy Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, economics

I have been trying to solve this particular game in terms of mixed strategies, but I am unable to find the strategy using expected payoffs. Is there a way to solve this particular problem?

There are two players:
Player 1's actions are T or B and player 2's actions are L, M or R.

Here is the table of payoffs written in the format (Player 1,Player 2):

**L  M  R**

2,2 0,3 1,2 **T**

3,1 1,0 0,2 **B**

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a solver, try these:

- http://banach.lse.ac.uk/
- http://gte.csc.liv.ac.uk/gte/builder/

If you want to know a method to solve the game, see my answer here:

[Mixed strategy nash equilibria in from $2\times N$ bimatrix form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/mixed-strategy-nash-equilibria-in-from-2-times-n-bimatrix-form/814586#814586)

Comment: Thank you very much for your guide! It helps in visualising which strategies are dominant and whether a mixed strategy gives at least higher payoffs than a pure strategy.

Comment: It does, but it also does more. It identifies which possible mixtures are candidates for being part of an equilibrium: for each vertex (i.e. mixture of player I, say) on the upper envelope, you just need to check if player II can use the best response strategies to this mixture to make player I indifferent between her two strategies, and if you can there is a corresponding equilibrium.