# Game Theory : Finding Nash equilibrium (non-cooperating)

Tags: game-theory

Consider the game bimatrix

\begin{bmatrix}
(1,5) & (3,1)
\\ 
 (4,2) & (2,3) 
\\
 (0.3) & (5,2)
\end{bmatrix}

It there a  way to reduce it to 2x2 bimatrix? I know how to solve that but get stuck when it is  3x2 bimatrix which I don't see a dominating row.

Comment: See my answer on how to solve a 2xN (or Nx2) bimatrix game using the upper envelope method: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72341/mixed-strategy-nash-equilibria-in-from-2-times-n-bimatrix-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first strategy of the first player can be discarded because it is strictly dominated by the mixed strategy which assigns a probability of $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ to each of the second and third pure strategies:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(4+0)&=2>1\ \ \text{and}\\
\frac{1}{2}(2+5)&=3.5>3\ .
\end{align}
So you can derive any Nash equilibrium of your $\ 3\times2\ $ bimatrix game from those of the game with the $\ 2\times2\ $ bimatrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 (4,2) & (2,3) \\
 (0,3) & (5,2)
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$